# Lightning controller is not calling apex class method

Tags: apex, lightning-components

I have created a lightning component that uploads the files into the content version after uploading the files the controller will call the apex class and apex class will fetch the pdf from the content version if pdf contains _ and household last name then it creates the case of that pdf. If files does not contain _ and household last name than it change the file name to 'Error_FILE name'. So here i am calling apex class method but the method is not invoking

Below is the component code

UploadeFilesForAuditRequest.cmp

```
<aura:component controller = "UploadeFilesForAuditRequestController" implements='force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction'
                    access='global' >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

<lightning:fileUpload label='Upload Multiple files'
                           multiple='true'
                          accept='.pdf, .png'
                          recordId='{!v.recordId}'
                          aura:id='multipleUpload'
                         onuploadfinished='{!c.handleUploadFinished}' />

</aura:component>



<aura:component controller = "UploadeFilesForAuditRequestController" implements='force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction'
                    access='global' >
 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

<lightning:fileUpload label='Upload Multiple files'
                           multiple='true'
                          accept='.pdf, .png'
                          recordId='{!v.recordId}'
                          aura:id='multipleUpload'
                         onuploadfinished='{!c.handleUploadFinished}' />

</aura:component>
```

UploadeFilesForAuditRequest.js

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (component, event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    // Get the list of uploaded files
     var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
    // show success message – with no of files uploaded
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Success!",
        "type" : "success",
        "message": uploadedFiles.length+" files has been uploaded successfully!"
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();


 var action = component.get("c.createPdf"); 
                 alert(component.get("v.recordId"));

     action.setParams({
        parentId : component.get("v.recordId") 
    });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());

        }
            else
            {
                alert("response unsuccessfull");
            }
        });



      var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
      dismissActionPanel.fire();
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

Below is the apex class

UploadeFilesForAuditRequestController

```
public class UploadeFilesForAuditRequestController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String createPdf(Id parentId)
    {   
        System.debug('Parent id' +parentId);
     Audit_Project__c auditProcess = new Audit_Project__c();
     List<ContentDocument> listToDelete = new List<ContentDocument>();

     if(HelperClass.firstRun)
     {
         List <ContentVersion> contentVersions = [select Id, LastModifiedById, PathonClient, VERSIONDATA , Title, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where FIRSTPUBLISHLOCATIONID =:parentId ];

         if(contentVersions != null){

             for(ContentVersion cv : contentVersions){

                 String fileName;

                 fileName = cv.PathOnClient;


                 if(fileName.contains('_')){
                     Integer lastIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('_');

                     String householdLastName  = fileName.substring(0, lastIndex);
                     String unit = fileName.substring(lastIndex + 1,fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

                     if(householdLastName != null && unit != null){

                         Case obj = new Case(); 
                         obj.Effective_Date_Certification__c = System.today();
                         obj.Origin = 'Email';
                         obj.PropertyCase__c= auditProcess.PropertyCase__c;
                         obj.Income_Set_Aside__c = 0;
                         //  obj.House_hold_name__c = '1';
                         //obj.Bedroom_Size__c = '1 BR';
                         obj.Certified_Income__c = 0;
                         obj.Household__c = householdLastName ;
                         obj.Property_Staff_Name__c = auditProcess.Property_Staff_Name__c;
                         obj.Unit__c = unit; 
                         obj.Audit_Request_Name__c = auditProcess.Id;
                         obj.OwnerId = auditProcess.OwnerId;
                         obj.Status = 'Awaiting Assignment';
                         if(auditProcess.Request_Type__c == 'Asset Management Audit'){
                             obj.RecordTypeId = '0124F000000MCiDQAW';    
                             obj.Application_Type__c = 'Asset Management Audit';
                         } else if(auditProcess.Request_Type__c == 'Desk Audit eFile'){
                             obj.RecordTypeId = '0124F000000MCi8QAG';
                             obj.Application_Type__c = 'Desk Audit eFile';
                         }

                         insert obj;
                         ContentVersion cvInsert = new ContentVersion();

                         cvInsert.PathOnClient = cv.PathOnClient;

                         cvInsert.Title = cv.Title;
                         cvInsert.FirstPublishLocationId = obj.Id;
                         cvInsert.VersionData = cv.VersionData;

                         insert cvInsert;
                         auditProcess.Total_number_of_valid_efiles__c =    auditProcess.Total_number_of_valid_efiles__c + 1; 
                         listToDelete.add(new ContentDocument(
                             Id = cv.ContentDocumentId 
                         ));

                     }
                     else{

                         /* Integer indexOfDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                         String nameWithoutExt = fileName.substring(0, indexOfDot);
                         String extension = fileName.substring(indexOfDot + 1 , fileName.length() -1 );*/
                         String nameWithoutExt = fileName;
                         cv.Title =  'ERROR_' +  nameWithoutExt ;

                         update cv;
                         auditProcess.Total_number_of_invalid_efiles_uploaded__c = auditProcess.Total_number_of_invalid_efiles_uploaded__c +1;


                     }
                 }else{

                     /*    Integer indexOfDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                           String nameWithoutExt = fileName.substring(0, indexOfDot);
                           String extension = fileName.substring(indexOfDot + 1 , fileName.length() -1 );
                           cv.Title = nameWithoutExt + '_Error' ;*/
                     String nameWithoutExt = fileName;
                     cv.Title =  'ERROR_' +  nameWithoutExt ;

                     update cv;
                     auditProcess.Total_number_of_invalid_efiles_uploaded__c = auditProcess.Total_number_of_invalid_efiles_uploaded__c +1;


                 }
             }

             auditProcess.Total_number_of_efiles_uploaded__c = auditProcess.Total_number_of_valid_efiles__c + auditProcess.Total_number_of_invalid_efiles_uploaded__c;

         delete listToDelete; 
         HelperClass.firstRun = false;
         }

     }
     return 'true';
    }
}
```

So here if  i upload the files then files are successfully uploaded but the cases were not created.

Comment: why u need ` $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();` before server call? try again after comment this line

Comment: I have tried by commenting this line $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire(); but still after uploading the file it i not creating the case.

Comment: what is your actual issue?, is it make server call successfully? any of your alerts messages are fired?

Comment: only these alert are fired -  alert(component.get("v.recordId"));

Comment: I think the apex class method is not invoking from controller

Comment: If you look at your debug logs in your Developer Console and the browser console, what do they tell you about what is happening here?

Comment: Can you try $A.enqueueAction(action); before firing dismissActionPanel